YOLO is not predicting the given image properly
I am trying YOLO for the first time.
I am following a video tutorial, and I wrote exact the code he wrote, but it is not working for me, and I have no idea why.
from ultralytics import YOLO
import numpy

model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt", "v8")

output = model.predict(source="dog.jpg", conf=0.25, save=True)

print(output)
print(output[0].numpy())

Image I am giving to the model:

Output I am getting:

I have tried it with other images but same results.

when i tried the same code in google collab it is working fine, it is not working on my system

What is your PC platform?

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz   1.80 GHz, 20G ram,AMD radeon (TM)535, win 11,

Try this. model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
model.export(format="onnx", dynamic=True)

One thisng is; did you update ultralytics 8.2.75 was R-released: Aug 8, 2024?

i have tried that still not working and yes i am using latest version
